# Time format in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a quick question about time format in Rails / ActiveRecord.

I want to have all the data since a specific date. I've done it for the 7 last days or for the last month but I want to have it since May 2017.

Here's what I came up with:

```
 %td= User.where('last_sign_in_at >= ?', 1.month.ago).sum(:sign_in_count) # As exemple
 %td= User.where('last_sign_in_at >= ?', 2017-05-01).sum(:sign_in_count) # Here's what I'm looking for.
```

But here's the error I get `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding date inside quotes: `'2017-05-01'`

Comment: Just as a minor suggestion, since you have ruby code there, consider adding comments like `As example` as an actual ruby comment with `#` instead of `/`; that will make it much easier to identify as a comment for people who are used to ruby *and* stack overflow will know to format it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass a string representing a date in sql like so:

```
...where("last_sign_in_at >= '2017-05-01'")...
```

Note the `'` around the date; they are there for SQL, not for Ruby, so the ruby string is between `"` to avoid escaping them as `\'`

If you have a date object, you can convert it to a string like this:

```
some_date = Date.today-360 # You can subtract days from Date objects in Ruby
...where('last_sign_in_at >= ?', some_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
# strftime = string-format-time (or something like that)
```

Otherwise, if you already have a string representing the date, you can just use that directly and most likely your database will know how to interpret the string as a date. Remember to add the `'` though.

Note: It might be possible to do "last_sign_in_at >= '>'" and then pass the string without `'`, but you'll have to try for yourself if that works or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you made it pretty clear and you helped me for a other issue I'm currently facing !
However, when I'm typing the `Date.now-360' I have an undefined method, any thoughts ?

Comment: Oh, it's `Date.today`, actually. My mistake :P (got confused with `Time.now`)

Comment: Yeah, that works as well. There's a tiny difference though: `DateTime.now` returns the current time (as a `DateTime` object), while `Date.today` returns the current `Date`, with no time information. When formatting as a string, `Date` inserts `0` for `%h` (hour), `%m` (minute), etc. while `DateTime` inserts the actual values.

Comment: _"If you have a date object ..."_ – ... you can pass it as-is. Rails takes care of converting it accordingly. Even if you have a string, you should probably convert it to a `Date` instance rather than passing the raw value.